# Jasonette Xcode 12.5 unable to arcive app because of 'SocketRocket/NSRunLoop+SRWebSocket.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, websocket, testflight, jasonette, bubble.io

I ran into a problem compiling a web app using Jasonette.

If I move the file to the location specified by the error, I get the same error.
The goal is to Archive the mobile app created by Jasonette for distribution with Testflight.

Xcode 12.5 preview and testing on the actual device have been completed, and there are no problems with operation.

So far, we have tried

Copying < ***`NSRunLoop+SRWebSocket.h`*** > to the desktop and moving it to Xcode.
Moved < ***`NSRunLoop+SRWebSocket.h`*** > into the SocketRocket file.
Moved < `***NSRunLoop+SRWebSocket.h***` > to #websocket.

I have not tested anything else.

How can I deal with this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgJbo.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fajPR.png)